# How would you go about writing a Parser similar to Facebook Graph Search

Tags: facebook, algorithm, parsing, search

I've read quite a few articles giving a bit of background information on how Facebook implemented their Graph Search. All of which seem to just glance over the actual implementation details of the parser they are using.

Such as https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-building-graph-search-beta/10151240856103920

From that page:

> We combined various parsing techniques to build a substring parser:
>   suppose a user inputs, say, "friends New York" and that we have
>   defined a comprehensive set of all the potential page titles our
>   system can handle. Our parser could then generate exactly the Graph
>   Search titles that contain the user's input, including things like
>   "friends who live in New York" and "friends who have visited New
>   York."  If we could find a way to appropriately rank those suggested
>   titles for the Graph Search typeahead, we would have a good start.

I'm really interested in learning about the methods one would use to tackle this problem. What Algorithm / Techniques would be used to write such a system ?

Any links would be much appreciated too.

Comment: I was searching for some links like you were (asking).. but cannot find much help..

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about implementing something similar.. wanted to ask Q here on SO and found that this is already asked..

Here is what I have been thinking to start with -

1. Assume facebook search engine "knows" about the underlying data store (a complex graph).  So the search engine understands key words like "Friends", "Relative" and other such relationships and does not treat them like a trivial word in english language.
2. In such case, a good idea could be to parse the user input (using client side javascript) to a JSON and send it over to the search engine .. a couple of benefits .. the parsing can be done on client side, save network bandwidth by not sending unwanted data, server side handling for the parsed input as JSON is way better..etc
3. Lets call this JSON fbJSON.. because apart from being a JSON .. it adheres to a certain format.. You can create a spec for your format.. such that the JSON that is sent over to search engine necessarily contains some information.. this can make life a bit easier .. just like we have geoJSON etc..
4. Use an NLP program to parse the user input into fbJSON [I still have to think about this]

This is a broad approach upon which i m embarking upon.. the only bottleneck is point #4..because I do not have much experience with NLPs..

Comment: Like the way of thinking and makes sense. I've since found another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873680/facebook-graph-search-information-retrieval-algorithm?rq=1 with a nice answer that could help too. But you seems to be much farther than me !